# Check Point Endpoint Security VPN on Linux

Tags: linux-mint, vpn, checkpoint

I am wondering whether it is possible to connect to this VPN on Linux (Mint in my case). I need it for work.

On their [Official Website](https://www.checkpoint.com/quantum/remote-access-vpn/#downloads), they do not offer a Linux Client.

My company provided me with a .p12 certificate file, protected by a password that I have.
They also provided me with the server address/gateway. That's all.

I tried connecting via SNX (command and output below):

```
➜  VPN Folder: snx -s <gateway> -c <filename>.p12             
Check Point's Linux SNX
build 800008304
Please enter the certificate's password:

SNX: Authentication failed
```

The password for the certificate is correct 100%, but I am still getting Authentication failed, which is weird.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, or some alternative to get it working? Is it even possible or will I have to get a Windows machine for this?

I also found this, but idk whether it could be useful (could not get it working either): https://hub.docker.com/r/kedu/snx-checkpoint-vpn#with-username-and-certificate

I also tried to use strongSwan instead of SNX, but could not get that working either.

I also tried cpyvpn (https://gitlab.com/cpvpn/cpyvpn)

I installed it with: pip install cpyvpn
Then did: cp_client -c /path/to/cert.p12

and got error:

Traceback (most recent call last):File "/home//.local/bin/cp_client", line 8, in sys.exit(main())File "/home//.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cpyvpn/client.py", line 474, in mainoptions.defhandler = utils.client_setup(options)File "/home//.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cpyvpn/utils.py", line 288, in client_setupctx.load_cert_chain(options.user_cert, password=ask_cert_pwd)ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4046)